# Swagger failing with Failed to load API definition (yet another thread)

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, asp.net-core-2.2

I tried to add swagger to an existing api and after failing alot, i decided to create a new solution, create a new asp.net core 2.2 api and added swagger as per

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio

The other posts regarding this issue seem all to indicate a situation where there are multiple httpverbs or none, which is not the case with the default valuescontroller. It gives me the error

> Failed to load API Definition.
>
> Fetch error, Service unavailable /swagger/v1/swagger.json

The actual json file  at api/swagger/v1/swagger.json actually renders correctly

My startup class is

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>{
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "My API", Version = "v1" });
        });
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
        });
        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

Im using Swachbuckle.AspNetCore v 4.01.

Comment: In my experience this generally happens when your controllers are setup incorrectly. Can you please post your controllers to review and we can check what the issue could be.

Answer (score 0):

```
        String SwaggerEndpoint = "/swagger/v1/swagger.json";

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseHsts();
            SwaggerEndpoint = "/andi/swagger/v1/swagger.json";
        }


        app.UseMvc();

        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
        {
            options.SwaggerEndpoint(SwaggerEndpoint, "My API");
            //options.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
        });
```